# how to repopulate an array once items have been removed swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uialertaction

I have an array and remove items so that they do not get repeated while calling elements from the array. However, once all elements are called I want to repopulate the array after OK is clicked on the alert. I can not figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

```
func select() {
    //random phrase
    if array.count > 0 {
        let Array = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
        let randNum = array[Array]
        // random phrase when program starts
        self.phrase.text = (array[Array])
        //removing
        array.remove(at: Array)
        array.
    } else {
        let  alert = UIAlertController(title: "Completed", message: "Click below to reload datac", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - do not name a variable `Array`. That's too confusing with the standard struct named `Array`. Besides, variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Use one array. Shuffle it. Keep an index and access each new index until you get to the end. Then reshuffle the array and reset the index to 0. No need to remove anything. No need for two array.

Comment: @maddy thanks, I've looked up how to do this, absolutely no idea. You know anywhere that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General psuedo code would be:

```
declare an array with items
invoke select() to choose a random item
    if array is empty 
        re-populate array after user prompt
        return
    end-if

    select random item and assign to phrase 
    remove item from array 
end select()
```

So something to the effect of:

```
var items = ["a", "b", "c"]
var phrase: String?

func selectRandomItem() {
    if items.isEmpty {
        let  alert = UIAlertController(title: "Completed", message: "Click below to reload datac", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            // repopulate `items` array
            items = ["a", "b", "c"]
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true)
        return
    }

    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count)))
    phrase = items[index]
    items.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it. I can just copy and paste my array in the handler to repopulate it. Simple and straight forward. Thanks again.

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` is obsolete since Swift 4.2. Use `items.indices.randomElement()`.